# How to get Accurate location from GPS in android?

Tags: android, gps, location

I m developing an App in which user have to mark attendance on a specific location. But when getting location from GPS, it is not accurate as User location. Its approx near to user location but not exact location.
Is there any idea to get exact location of the User in Android?
If any please tell me.

Thanks for your aswers

Comment: GPS location always has some error. What is the accuracy you're getting? If it's within few meters from the actual point then it's fine and you can't get any better accuracy.

Comment: You may use your mobile Networks to get the current location instead of GPS. But GPs would be more accurate than NETWORK PROVIDER to get the current location.

Answer (score 0):

Give these permissions in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Comment: Thanks for Replying, all these permissions are given. Still not be able to find accurate location